# CLion memory usage of running program

Tags: memory, memory-management, clion

Is there a tool in CLion to view the memory usage (statistics) of a running program. I look for something similar like the Diagnostic Tool in Visual Studio. With that it is possible to view the Process Memory over time and get the maximum.

[image]

Is this possible with the memory view somehow or do I need to install a plugin?

I am also not interested in the memory usage of CLion. Instead I want to know the amount of memory used by the program that I am executing.

Comment: You can attach an external profiler to a program, if you're not debugging it. On Mac, for example, XCode's Instruments' profiler works on any process.

Comment: I don't know whether there is a CLion tool, but you can use the combination of **valgrind** and **massif-visualizer**. Run ` valgrind --tool=massif ./your-program` to generate a massif file, which can be then visualized in the **massif-visualizer** GUI application.